# cin double and string without space results in error

Tags: c++, cin

The following program outputs `Error` on a Mac Mojave (`AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046`) when entering for example `10cm` (notice there is no space between the value and the string input). The same input works under Ubuntu 16.04 (`GNU 5.4.0`) (output: `Working`).

```
int main() {
    double val {0.0};
    string unit {" "};

    cout << "Enter a double value followed by a unit (cm , m, in, ft) with or without a space in between (followed by 'Enter'):\n";

    if (cin >> val)
    {
        cout << "Working val" << '\n';
        if (cin >> unit)
        {
            cout << "Working unit" << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error unit" << '\n';
            auto f = cin.fail();
            auto b = cin.bad();
            cout << "f: " << f << ", b: " << b << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error val" << '\n';

        auto f = cin.fail();
        auto b = cin.bad();

        cout << "f: " << f << ", b: " << b << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is `cin` going into a bad state under Mac OS?

Here is the complete output under Mac OS:

```
Enter a double value followed by a unit (cm , m, in, ft) with or without a space in between (followed by 'Enter'):
10cm
Error val
f: 1, b: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It is working when I enter for example `10 cm` (with a space):

```
Enter a double value followed by a unit (cm , m, in, ft) with or without a space in between (followed by 'Enter'):
10 cm
Working val
f: 0, b: 0
Working unit
f: 0, b: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

**Edit: Previous (complete) question:** I am trying to do the drill 7 of chapter 4 from Programming Principles and Practice using C++:

Change the body of the loop so that it reads just one double each time around. Define two variables to keep track of which is the smallest and which is the largest value you have seen so far. Each time through the loop write out the value entered. If it’s the smallest so far, write the smallest so far after the number. If it is the largest so far, write the largest so far after the number.

Add a unit to each double entered; that is, enter values such as 10cm, 2.5in, 5ft, or 3.33m. Accept the four units: cm, m, in, ft. Assume conversion factors 1m == 100cm, 1in == 2.54cm, 1ft == 12in. Read the unit indicator into a string. You may consider 12 m (with a space between the number and the unit) equivalent to 12m (without a space).

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

bool legalUnit(string unit)
{
    if (unit == "cm" || unit == "m" || unit == "in" || unit == "ft")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


int main() {
    bool first {true};
    double val {0.0};
    double smallest {0.0};
    double largest {0.0};
    string unit {" "};

    cout << "Enter a double value followed by a unit (cm , m, in, ft) with or without a space in between (followed by 'Enter'):\n";

    while (cin >> val >> unit)
    {

        if (legalUnit(unit))
        {
            cout << val << unit << '\n';

            if (first == true)
            {
                first = false;
                smallest = val;
                largest = val;
            }
            else if (val < smallest)
            {
                cout << " the smallest so far.\n";
            }
            else if (val > largest)
            {
                cout << " the largest so far.\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles without problems on a mac and linux and entering a number followed by whitespace and a unit, such as `10 in` works.

**Now to my problem:** On a mac, if I enter for example `10in` the program exits immediately because the `cin >> val >> unit` returns false. On linux the same input works, meaning the loop is entered.

Is there anything I need to consider regarding the compiler? I am using CLion with the default settings (auto detected compiler) for Mac Mojave 10.14.5 and Ubuntu 16.04.

**Can someone on a mac confirm that an input such as `10cm` is not working?**

Comment: Rather than `if (first == true)` initialize `smallest` to the largest possible number and and `largest` to the smallest possible number.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that because it is not taught in this part of the book. I will update the program with initialised values. However, the behavior is still the same on Mojave.

Comment: Code should work. Make absolutely certain there are no transcription errors. Back up your code and rip out everything except the bare essentials. Something like https://ideone.com/PwoCQB . Then start adding stuff back in until the program breaks. The bug is almost certainly related to the last stuff added.

Comment: You updated the code. Lemme check again. First glance, `legalUnit` could be reduced to `return unit == "cm" || unit == "m" || unit == "in" || unit == "ft";`

Comment: Thats true thanks. I will add a simpler example to get more focus on my main problem than the code itself.

Comment: Unrelated: You're not at this point yet, but remember that 3m is larger than 10cm.

Comment: [mcve] could be [6 lines only](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5GC1zzBMkcYdsQmV) ;)

Comment: try to keep things simple. When trying to understand in and output you dont need a function to check units or logic to find biggest/smallest or loops and all that

Comment: And if it turns out that you do need that extra stuff to expose the bug, the bug's not where you thought it was, and that is great information to have.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using on the Mac? You could find a little more info by breaking the expression apart: what are `cin.fail()` and `cin.bad()` after `cin >> val` and after `cin >> unit`?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess it is no bug but a problem with different c++ implementations behaving differently under mac and linux. How do I find the compiler under CLion?

Comment: I added the output of `cin.fail()` and `cin.bad()` after using `cin >> val >> unit`. I will try it separately now and check the results of `cin.fail()` and `cin.bad()`.

Comment: I found the compiler from the cmake output: Mac: `The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046` and for Ubuntu: `The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0`

Comment: On mac os with the input `10cm`, `cin` fails after `cin >> val`. It seems that this implementation fails to stop reading only the double value.

Comment: Any ideas why `cin >> val` is not stopping to read after the double value right before the string starts? Instead it is going into a bad state.

Comment: One of the first things to get rid of when hunting mystery bugs is magic headers and `using namespace std;` See what happens if you stop including std_lib_facilities.h and instead include <iostream> and <string> and fully qualify  `std::string`, `astd::cin` and `std::cout`. Could be something hidden in the dark depths of std_lib_facilities.h that's conflicting on the Mac in ways that Stroustrup couldn't foresee while writing his books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [bug in libc++](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17782) (reported back in 2013 I might add).

If a number is followed by a letter in an input stream without an intervening space, then reading this number may or may not fail, depending on the letter. The "bad" letters are A through F, I, N, P, and X (and their lower case counterparts).

An astute reader will notice that those are exactly the letters that can make up hexadecimal constants (yes P is one of them) and the words NAN and INF.

Among other characters that behave the same way are the plus sign, the minus sign, and the decimal point (the reason is obvious).